# Have mktime() ignore DST and local time zone in C++

Tags: c++, tm, mktime

Our system receives data from a vendor in ASCII format "20210715083015".  This time is US Eastern time, and is already adjusted for Daylight Savings.

Our backend needs this time in nanoseconds since Epoch.  I'm trying to use mktime() to do the conversion, but mktime() insists on adding an hour for DST, even when I force tm_isdst to 0.

Here's the code snippet:

```
std::tm tmstr{};
<breakdown ASCII time into tm structure>

tmstr.tm_isdst = 0;
cout << "isdst before: " tmstr.tm_isdst;
time_t seconds = std::mktime(&tmstr);
cout << ", isdst after: " tmstr.tm_isdst << endl;
```

Here's the output:

```
isdst before: 0, isdst after: 1
```

It's ignoring the set value of 0, and applying its own conversion.

How do I use mktime(), or something equivalent, without it trying to adjust the time to my timezone?  I'd rather not have to internally set timezones, I just want it to do a straight conversion from a tm structure to seconds.

This is g++ version 7.3.1, under Redhat version 6.10.

Comment: Can you use [`gmtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime)?  You'll have to adjust your string to UTC, of course.

Comment: If you look at the man page for mktime, you'll see that is_dst is updated after the call, regardless what you set it to, to give an /indication/ as to whether dst would be in operation at said time.

Comment: @bib Unfortunately, so documentation I've seen for mktime() says it respects the setting of is_dst on entry, but obviously that's incorrect.

Comment: @PaulSanders That would require checking to see if we'd cross the day boundary, and also I'd have to know if DST was currently in effect.

Comment: why don't just use `std::chrono`?

Answer (score 2):

> It's ignoring the set value of 0

No, it is not ignoring that member.

`mktime()` takes `.tm_isdst` into account and then adjusts all the `struct tm` members to their *usual values* for that date, thus a change to `.tm_isdst` **and** `.tm_hour` is expected in OP's case as the `tmstr` is in daylight time for "20210715" July 15th.

---

> How do I use `mktime()`, or something equivalent, without it trying to adjust the time to my timezone?

`mktime()` is a local time conversion.  The usual approach is let `mktime()` deduce the daylight flag.

```
tmstr.tm_isdst = -1;
```

---

> This time is US Eastern time, and is already adjusted for Daylight Savings.

No, you are asserting it is US *standard* Eastern time ([EST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)). US Eastern time ([ET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)) has daylight adjustments.

Change your time zone from one with daylight and standard periods to a zone with only standard.  Research `setenv()`.  Perhaps as simple as:

```
// Implementation dependent code.
setenv("TZ", "EST5", 1);
tzset();
time_t seconds = mktime(&tmstr);
```

---

**Key issue missing: was the **`time_t`** result correct?**

Ignore `tmstr` for a moment.  What `time_t` value was reported?  What `time_t` value was expected?

I suspect OP did get the right `time_t` value, just not the expected result in `struct tm`.

Comment: I don't bother to look at the tm structure after the conversion.  It gave back the time_t set an hour ahead.

Comment: @FlyboyWilson Please post all the value of all members of `tmstr` just before `gmtime()` function  and the function's return numeric result.  What is environment var `TZ`?  "20210715083015" does not show how `tmstr` was set.  Likely it was done right, but perhaps not?

Comment: @FlyboyWilson "I don't bother to look at the tm structure after the conversion." is unclear given the question's  `cout << ", isdst after: " tmstr.tm_isdst << endl;` after `mktime()`.

Answer (score 1):

Easier to post here...

From the `mktime()` man page, you're not reading what is written...

> The `mktime()` function  converts  a  broken-down  time structure, expressed as local time, to calendar time representation.  The function ignores the values supplied by the caller in the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` fields.  The value specified in the `tm_isdst` field informs `mktime()` whether or not daylight saving time (DST) is in effect for the time supplied in the `tm` structure: a positive value means DST is in effect; zero means that DST is not in effect; and a negative value means that `mktime()` should (use  timezone  information  and system databases to) attempt to determine whether DST is in effect at the specified time.
>
> The `mktime()` function modifies the fields of the `tm` structure as follows: `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` are set to values determined from the contents of the other fields; if structure members are outside their valid interval, they will be normalized (so that, for example, 40 October is changed into 9 November); `tm_isdst` is set (regardless of its initial value) to a positive value or to 0, respectively, to indicate whether DST is or is not in effect at the specified time.  Calling `mktime()` also sets  the  external  variable  `tzname`  with information about the current timezone.

Comment: I did read it, I just misinterpreted that it would adjust it whether I wanted it or not, even when I provided valid values for the other fields.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully, you could use the `timegm()` function (not to confound with the `gmtime()` function... see below for more info).

The `mktime()` function has a state. If the last time it was used with `isdst` set to 0, then using `isdst = -1` will use 0. If the last time you used it with `isdst` set to 1, then using `isdst = -1` will use 1. This is true only if the function is called with a time when the time change happens (within that 1h window). Other functions are not unlikely to change that variable too (i.e. the `localtime()` may also affect that state, I haven't tested that).

```
// a date when the time change happened (Sun Oct 26 01:08:48 PST 1980)
time_t et = 341399328;

struct tm t = {};
localtime_r(&et, &t);

struct tm ot = {};
ot.tm_year = t.tm_year;
ot.tm_mon = t.tm_mon;
ot.tm_mday = t.tm_mday;
ot.tm_hour = t.tm_hour;
ot.tm_min = t.tm_min;
ot.tm_sec = t.tm_sec;

ot.tm_isdst = 1;
std::cerr << " +--> " << mktime(&ot) << " (1)\n";
ot.tm_isdst = 0;
std::cerr << " +--> " << mktime(&ot) << " (0)\n";
ot.tm_isdst = -1;
std::cerr << " +--> " << mktime(&ot) << " (-1)\n"; // same as 0

ot.tm_isdst = 0;
std::cerr << " +--> " << mktime(&ot) << " (0)\n";
ot.tm_isdst = 1;
std::cerr << " +--> " << mktime(&ot) << " (1)\n";
ot.tm_isdst = -1;
std::cerr << " +--> " << mktime(&ot) << " (-1)\n"; // same as 1
```

The output should always be the same as the input (i.e. convert from `time_t` to `struct tm` and vice versa). Instead I get:

> 341399328 -> 1980/10/26 1:8:48
> +--> 341395728 (1)
> +--> 341399328 (0)
> +--> 341399328 (-1)
> +--> 341399328 (0)
> +--> 341395728 (1)
> +--> 341395728 (-1)

So, more or less, you can't trust the `mktime()` conversions.

There are now two new functions: `timegm()` and `timelocal()`. The `timelocal()` function is the same as the `mktime()`. The `timegm()` totally ignores the locale timezone, so you can convert UTC time back and forth properly. The converse being `gmtime()`.

In other words:

1. `time_t` to `struct tm` with `gmtime()`
2. `struct tm` to `time_t` with `timegm()`

and the input `time_t` in (1) will always equal the output `time_t` in (2).

Answer (score -1):

It would seem that there is no way to prevent mktime() from applying DST. But it does tell us if it did add the extra hour or not. So one easy fix is as follows...

```
  time_t t = mktime( &tmst );
  if(tmst.tm_isdst == 1)
    t -= 60*60;
```